# Python pandas replace function not working with escaped characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

I've already looked at half a dozen SO questions on the Python 3 pandas `replace` function, and none of them apply to this situation. I have the text `\"` present in some data, and I need to eliminate ONLY the backslash. Toy code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a'])
df.loc[0] = ['Replace \\"']
df
```

with output

```
            a
0  Replace \"
```

My goal is to rewrite `df` so that it looks like this:

```
           a
0  Replace "
```

None of the following work:

```
df.replace('\\"', '"', regex=True)
df.replace('\\"', '\"', regex=True)
df.replace('\\\"', '\"', regex=True)
df.replace('\\\"', '\"', regex=True)
df.replace(r'\"', r'"', regex=True)
df.replace({'\\"':'"'}, regex=True)
df.replace({r'\"':r'"'}, regex=True)
df.replace(to_replace=r'\"', value=r'"', regex=True)
df.replace(to_replace=r'\"', value=r'"', regex=False)
```

I can't search just for the backslash, because I have legitimate backslashes elsewhere in the data that I don't want to replace.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply`:

```
In [2596]: df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(r'\\"', r'"')) 
Out[2596]: 
           a
0  Replace "
```

If there's only column in question, you can also do this, which will be a little more performant:

```
In [2614]: df['a'].str.replace(r'\\"', r'"')
Out[2614]: 
0    Replace "
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: Can you please edit so that you're searching for the backslash AND the quote? I mentioned in my question that I can't search only for the backslash, as I have legit backslashes in the data.

Comment: Looks like `df.apply(lambda x:x.str.replace(r'\\"', r'"'))` works.

Comment: Yes. I updated my `lambda` code part. Please check.

Comment: That doesn't work. You need the `r` prefix to tell it it's raw.

Comment: Ahh my bad. Updated now.

Comment: It works; my only question now is: will this be performant on dataframes with, say, 70M rows and 6 columns? I guess I'll find out. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I've added another solution in my answer. Please check.

Comment: That works, too. I might know in advance which columns might have the offending text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df.a.str.replace('\\','')
```

result:

```
0    Replace "
```

For the whole data frame you can use:

```
for col in df:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(r'\\','')
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my original question, and in my comments, I can't search for backslashes only, because I have legit backslashes in my data I don't want to replace.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the question in first place. I'm glad you found what you looking for. Another way to do what you're aiming to achieve is import re 
df.a.apply(lambda x:re.sub(r'\\"',r'"',x)). I hope this helps you. Cheers.